# why keypress doesn't work with on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to catch enter event for an input bar

```
$("input[name='search']").on("keypress", function(e){
    if (e.which == '13') {
        alert('code');
    }
});
```

html

```
<input name="search" type="input"/>
```

Comment: that's a really bad idea; among other things, it can catch Enter keypresses from browser autocomplete.  why not intercept `submit`?

Comment: This fiddle as per ur code is working what is the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/7A2g8/

Comment: works fine for me. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L23aJ/). im guessing you prolly have missed something like jquery import

Comment: Are you sure you've loaded jQuery? What does the console say?

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
$("input[name='search']").keyup(function () {
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `Ready function`  for `.on`

```
    $(function(){ // or $(document).ready(function()

         $("input[name='search']").on("keypress", function(e){
        if (e.which == '13')
        { 
            alert('code');
        }
    });  
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CKSLD/